# Classification of very large number of samples using LDA

Tags: discriminant-analysis

I have a dataset with tens of thousands of samples and only 7 features. I want to use [linear discriminant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) to classify these samples into 2 classes. The `Python` [scikit-learn's](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/lda_qda.html#shrinkage) LDA package is used. However, the results become very strange, as I found that the classification is dominated by a single feature, as shown in [image: the attached figure]. LDA coefficients are:

```
9259.89517281, -191.60635381,   403.78787046,   -79.33404653,  -93.1753486 ,   110.23429443,   -41.93012569
```

As all values in all features are `>=0` and scaled between `0 and 10`, the coefficients indicate the classification is dominated by the first feature. I think all features should be important for the classification. Is there a way to solve this? I have tried `Shrinkage` provided by the package I used, but seems not work.

Comment: Imagine that you have two classes (clouds) in 2D space, and the clouds are separated only along X axis and not along Y axis. Then, obviously, feature X is the only "important" discriminator of the classes.

Comment: Yor question has nothing to do with the amount of data points.